# Is there ever a case where a mapping is not preserved/closed under scalar multiplication.

Tags: matrices

Is there ever a case where a mapping is not preserved/closed under scalar multiplication? Every problem I have encountered has always been closed under scalar multiplication. However, closed under addition is easier to see if a mapping is linear or not. What mappings are there that prove otherwise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "linear mapping" by definition preserves both scalar multiplication and vector addition.

If you allow an arbitrary mapping, then anything goes.  For example, let $V=\mathbb{R}^2$, we can define $f:V\to V$ via $f(x,y)=(1,2)$.  This mapping sends everything to the same vector, namely $(1,2)$.  This one is not linear, it preserves neither scalar multiplication nor vector addition.

Comment: Or perhaps, for something that may feel less like a cheat, $f(x,y)=f(x+1,y)$.